# Microservice database problems

Tags: mysql, spring-cloud

After the microservice database is divided, if the data to be displayed by service A needs to be associated with the table of database B, the database can't use join operation after the microservice is divided. How to deal with it in the current general way of enterprises? My current solution is use the 'feign' to invoke other services to get the data, and stick it into A service's object, if there are any associated table, you need to use 'feign' many times, I don't think this is a good solution, so the code amount will accumulate very much.

Comment: How is your microservice database divided? If its a single database server with different database, you can reference another database on the same server with `db2.table`.

Comment: If it's about retrieving "joined" data you can use the CQRS pattern.